# Refresh datagridview after updating text in another child form

Tags: datagridview, refresh

I have a datagridview that bind to  a list of keywords.

```
      void BindKeywordData()
    {
        keywords = kbo.GetQueryable(false).ToList();
        srcKeywords.ResetBindings(false);
        dgKeywords.DataSource = null;
        dgKeywords.DataSource = srcKeywords;
        dgKeywords.Update();
    }
    private void FormKeywords_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BindKeywordData();
    }
```

There is an "EDIT" link column that when cell content clicked I can edit the information of the specific row on another form. That form frmKeditor contains a textbox and a save button which work perfect so I don't post the code here.

```
     FormKeywordEditor frmKEditor = new FormKeywordEditor(kw);
                DialogResult dresult = frmKEditor.ShowDialog();                    
                if (dresult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    BindKeywordData();
                }
```

The issue is the BindKeywordData doesn't refresh the datagrid view (the data did change, I have checked directly by Sql Studio). When I add new records using another form the datagridview immediately show new rows, but the text of the edited row still unchange until I close the form and reopen again. Even I put a button on to the form and call BindKeywordData() directly the datagridview still not show changes of the edited row. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer myself:
I am not supposed to update the database from a dialog because the owner form will not know about it. So at the dialog I just change some value of the keyword then call kbo.save() on the main form, like this:

```
     FormKeywordEditor frmKEditor = new FormKeywordEditor(kw);
            DialogResult dresult = frmKEditor.ShowDialog();                    
            if (dresult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                kbo.save();
                BindKeywordData();
            }
```